# Computing expectation value of Pauli-$x$ operator for a single qubit, given a Hamiltonian matrix.

Tags: information-theory, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am working through some introductory quantum mechanics materials, and I am stuck on the following problem...

Suppose we are working on a single qubit and we are given the Hamiltonian to be $$H=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta^* \\\ \beta & \alpha\end{pmatrix}$$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ and both $\alpha, |\beta| \neq 0$.

We are also allowed to assume that $|ψ(t = 0)⟩ = |0⟩$.

From this, I need to compute the expectation value of the Pauli-$x$ operator, i.e. $$⟨ψ(t)|σ_x|ψ(t)⟩$$ and determine whether it can be independent of the value of $t$.

I am pretty stuck with this. I know that the time evolution is determined through a unitary operator, so I have $$|ψ(t)⟩ = U(t, 0)|ψ(0)⟩ = U(t,0)|0⟩.$$ However, I do not understand how I am to find $U$ and actually perform any computations?

I then tried to find the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian, $E_{\pm} = \alpha \pm 2\sqrt{|\beta|^2}$. This then let me diagonalise the Hamiltonian as $H|E_{\pm}⟩ = E_{\pm}|E_{\pm}⟩$, thus giving a second basis of quantum states. But again, I do not understand how this would tie in to performing the computation...

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The evolution operator is just $\text{exp} (-iH t)$.

Comment: @MohammadAlhejji But would we not usually write the time evolution in terms of the eigenstates as $\exp(itE_+)|E_+\rangle + \exp(itE_-)|E_-\rangle$? I don't understand how I would compute an expectation value from this?

Answer (score 0):

For a time-independent Hamiltonian $H$, it is a direct consequence of Schrödinger's equation that the time evolution operator is given by the unitary operator $U_{t} := \text{exp} (-i H t)$. Once an expression for this operator is found, the expectation value of an observable $S$ given an initial state $\psi_0$ is
\begin{align}
< \psi_t | S | \psi_t > \; = \; < \psi_0 | U_{t}^* S U_t | \psi_0 >. 
\end{align}